# Mixed group example

Tags: abstract-algebra, torsion-groups

Is $(\Bbb Q \setminus \{0\},\cdot)$ a mixed group?

That is, there are two elements distinct from the identity in such a way that one of them is of finite order and the other is of infinite order?
I got the example, but can't find that two elements.
TIA.

Comment: Please flesh out all of your ideas and what you've tried!

Comment: what is $\mathbb Q\{0\}$?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean $\mathbb{Q}^\times = \mathbb{Q} \setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: Which of the elements can't you find?